# Would my sister, who studies in England on a visa, suffer retaliation if she discloses Chronic Fatigue Syndrome?

Tags: united-kingdom, disability

My sister studies at a university in England on a Tier 4 Visa, and her physician diagnosed her with [Chronic fatigue syndrome (CFS)](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/Chronic-fatigue-syndrome/Pages/Introduction.aspx) that is severely stigmatized and often judged a fake illness. Her CFS worsens when she lives alone in England - even after sleeping for 9 hours, by mid-afternoon, she becomes easily fatigued before she starts to study, after going to classes, cooking her own meals (she's vegan), and washing dishes.

1) She is considering disclosing her CFS to her university, but worries that the university would terminate her studies or expel her, because they may judge her too fatigued or weak to succeed in her studies from CFS.

2) Even if her university doesn't expel her, if they inform the UK Home Office of her CFS, then the Home Office may be the one to judge her as too fatigued to succeed, and terminate her visa and stop her from studying in England.

3) Moreover, the Home Office and the university would be sly enough not to state CFS as the reason because this may be illegal, but would invent some other reason to stop her studies.

Comment: Would your sister be able to successfully complete her studies without help and allowances from the university? That is a question she should discuss with her doctor. If the answer is "No", she has nothing to lose by disclosing, and may gain help she needs.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I agree. Her concern should be more if she can succeed and study, not if she can keep the visa if she is not able to study at all due to her condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your fears are misplaced. Universities only wish to know about disabilities in order to make allowances for students. By declaring the disability, your sister will enable the university to consider her condition if her condition causes her difficulty in meeting the course requirements. For example, if her condition means that she is unable to leave her accommodation to turn in coursework, she may be allowed to have a deadline extension. The alternative is that she misses a deadline, and the university believes this is due to poor time planning or laziness. *This* is what would lead to her being removed from her course. Informing the university about the disability in advance will explain the missed deadline, and could help ensure that she *isn't* removed from her course. Removing someone from their course simply for declaring a disability would be completely illegal.

With regards to the Home Office, I don't think the university has any duty or reason to inform them about disability. Regardless, the Home Office doesn't care about disability, only about your sister continuing to be enrolled on her course, and attending the pointless Tier 4 census. The Home Office has enough of a backlog of work already. They have absolutely no interest in removing your sister from the country for having a disability.

If your sister is still worried about informing the university authorities about her condition, she should certainly contact her student union. Most student unions have a disability officer who is elected from among the students to help and represent students with disabilities. They are independent from the university, and have no interest in informing anybody else about things that they are told in confidence. Talking to them might help allay your sister's fears.